# How to use In App Purchase with dynamic products and Dynamic price?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am using in app purchase first time and i have added IAP into my app which work fine with sandbox account. But my app was rejected due to

```
11.7 Details

Additionally, we noticed that your In-App Purchase product was set to an incorrect Purchasability Type.

Your app includes several products, however, only one Consumable In App Purchase has been submitted for review.

Next Steps

Based on product functionality, please use the Non-Consumable In-App Purchase type for each product.
```

Now i have couple of question-

```
1. Does I have to create manually different IAP for Different product because they are coming from server side with different price in ItunesConnect Account?

2. If I made product Non-Consumable then I have to add Restore button. How can i use and give restore button for all products?

3. My last question is My app successfully clear testflight beta app review process and ready to test but apple reject same build after submitted for review. I want to know testflight review process are differ from app submission review?
```

My English is not to good but i am trying to explain my problem as much i can.

Thanks in advance.Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Yes, you have to create iAP for products manually. When submitting app, you can send to review currently available IAPs, later after review you can submit new IAPs to the review without updating the app. First IAP has to be submitted with initial or new version of the app.
2. Yes, you have to add Restore button. When restored, all non-consumable IAPs get restored, no need separate buttons for each.
3. Yes, beta review and review for the App Store differ a lot. On beta review I think they just test functional eligibility of the app, while on the App Store review they check everything, also, reviewers may change.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. According to your answer if my app approved with initial product. after that if i add new product then how can check my New IAP product  id with in app with New productID coming from server side?

Comment: After fetching new product ids from server, you make a call to get available products with the array of the ids using product request `SKProductsRequest`, after getting product from Apple server, you can continue with the purchase.